# Ecto how to disable autogenerating for not primitive type

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have kinda simple model:

```
defmodule Review do
  use Web, :model
  use Arc.Ecto.Schema

  schema "reviews" do
    field :description, :string
    field :file, File.Type, autogenerate: false
  end
end
```

Where `File.Type` relates to [arc_ecto](https://github.com/stavro/arc_ecto) package.

Actually, I don't want `field :file` to be generated by default, because it goes in controversial with `arc_ecto`.

But `autogenerate` doesn't work here:

```
%Review{} #=> { description: nil, file: nil }
```

What can I do to make `%Review{}` to generate struct only with `description` key?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Structs have always a fixed set of keys - therefore some value for each key is always required.

Comment: Is there any hack to avoid this?

Comment: That would completely defeat the purpose of structs. You could use plain maps.